# Sidebar Transition for offcanvas navigation onclick remove class

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have recently end up with [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/28/transitions-for-off-canvas-navigations/) for off canvas navigation. If you see in their demo what they did is if we want to close the sidebar one have to click anywhere inside the body and a class from the sidebar has been removed to slide out the sidebar.

What I want is the same effect is to be done while on clicking a close button inside the sidebar the sidebar has to be slide out. How to achieve this?

This is the code they used to remove the class.

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'st-container' ),
        buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#st-trigger-effects > button' ) ),
        // event type (if mobile use touch events)
        eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
        resetMenu = function() {
            classie.remove( container, 'st-menu-open' );
        },
        bodyClickFn = function(evt) {
            if( !hasParentClass( evt.target, 'st-menu' ) ) {
                resetMenu();
                document.removeEventListener( eventtype, bodyClickFn );
            }
        };
```

Thanks

Comment: `class from the sidebar has been removed to slide out the sidebar`. Right? then remove that class on your close button click event

Comment: Yeah, I know but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your familiar with jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Your-close button-id').on('click', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('st-menu-open');
        });
    });
```